# Is this an adverbial or a noun clause?

Tags: conjunctions

> Yet the days crept by, and there could be no doubt **that** Fluffy was
>   still alive and well behind the locked door. (Harry Potter)

Do you call the that-clause as an adverbial clause, or a noun clause in apposition with the previous noun? If you call it an adverbial one, what would you say it modifies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one approach at least, you can simply say that the clause is the **complement** of *doubt*, just as you would say that it was the complement of *doubt* if the latter was a verb.

Notice that it is in some sense part of the **argument structure** of the noun *doubt* that it can **select** a clause. Or in other words, you can't readily apply the same structure to any old noun: **the book that the universe is large*, **his tolerance that Mary is rude*. There's a property specifically of the word *doubt* (and some other nouns) that "licenses" the clause.

The term *apposition* is usually reserved for a much more general structure where you're implying that one phrase "equates" to another, but where the first doesn't necessarily "select" or "license" the second as such.

Answer (score 4):

It's a *That*-complement, i.e, a noun clause. But it's not in apposition; rather, it's the object complement of the verb *doubt*

- *No one doubted that Fluffy was ...*

Nouns that are derived from verbs often take the same kind of object [complements](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf) as the verbs do, occasionally with a preposition. So we get

- *He attempted to help her ~ his attempt to help her.*
- *He enjoys (running) decathlons ~ his enjoyment of (running) decathlons*
- *She doubts that Fluffy is alive ~ her doubt that Fluffy is alive*